# Limit of sequence and integral 5

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\int_n^{n+7}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}}$. I guess $0 \le \int_n^{n+7}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} \le \frac{sin(n+7)}{n+7}$ so using the sqeeze theorem the  answer is $0$. Am I right?

Comment: How do you get that upper bound? Certainly $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ is *not* an increasing function. And, even if it were, you'd need a factor of $7$ there? And why the lower bound of $0$?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but squeezing is the right approach:
$$\left|\int_{n}^{n+7}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx\right|\leq \int_{n}^{n+7}\frac{dx}{x}\leq \frac{1}{n}\int_{n}^{n+7}dx=\frac{7}{n}.$$